# Is there a way to build native .NET with Github Actions

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to know, if it's possible to build and deploy native .NET apps (*framework 4.8*)
with Github Actions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Like @Guillaume Sasdy answer, an YAML that seems working
>
> Source : [Github Forum](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/How-to-build-project-targeting-Net35-with-GitHub-Actions/td-p/36191)

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [windows-latest]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Build DotNET
        run: |
           cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\"
           .\MSBuild.exe $Env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE\  **SLN or project**
```

Comment: Thank you for the quote. It's nice of yours if you mark my answer as accepted, or upvote it, or both. That's the currency on SO ;-)

Comment: This answer is for me not a long term solution, because, it's depedent of the windows images that is run,

Comment: A .NET app do run on Windows. What could be the issue with such an image? You think you'll not be able to configure it as you would like?

Comment: Are you sure you need to specify the full path, did you try just running `msbuild.exe` and it didn't work?

Comment: @smac89 `msbuild` was never added to `PATH`, many projects either provide full path or use `vswhere` to find it

Comment: @GuillaumeSasdy, You can't select the SDK, for me this isn't a problem because I use the latest .NET SDK

Comment: @lupaulus Doesn't it use the latest SDK because of `MSBuild\Current\Bin ` in the run path? Try to change something in that `run` variable (path, arguments) and you may be able to define a specific version of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

According to their [landing page](https://github.com/features/actions): yes.

> GitHub Actions makes it easy to automate all your software workflows,
>   now with world-class CI/CD. **Build, test, and deploy your code right
>   from GitHub.**
>
> GitHub Actions supports Node.js, Python, Java, Ruby, PHP, Go, Rust,
>   **.NET**, and more.

That link may help: [How to build project targeting Net35 with GitHub Actions](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/How-to-build-project-targeting-Net35-with-GitHub-Actions/td-p/36191)

Comment: Yes but if you read the documentation, they say .NET Core and they doesn't write something about native .NET

Comment: How to build project targeting Net35 with GitHub Actions: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/How-to-build-project-targeting-Net35-with-GitHub-Actions/td-p/36191 Does that help you? You need to use msbuild.exe command on a Windows Server. If it helps, I will link it in the answer.